# Materialized Views support to Big query or any similar functionality

Tags: sql, oracle, google-bigquery

I want a particular query to get triggered and update a table every time any change in any particular table occurs.
Example: Table 'A' gets updated with some records. Now, I want to take some specified columns and insert some records from Table 'A' to Table 'B' based on a query. Basically this insertion should be triggered automatically whenever Table 'A'  goes through any kind of change.
In Oracle, There is a concept of Materialized Views which does nothing but running a query every time a specified table data gets changed. It keeps the physical storage of data resulted by query written as View. 
Does Big query supports such functionality? if not, is there any workaround to achieve the same?

Comment: why don't you use a simple trigger on table A to insert necessary values on table B?

Comment: BigQuery does not support such functionality!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I was not sure if it did or not. Thanks for confirming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest to what you described can be done as below and in Legacy SQL only (because Standard SQL does not support [`Range Decorators`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators#range_decorators)):

So, the idea is -

1 - Each N minutes you query last N minutes (for sake of example assume N=10 min)

```
SELECT * FROM [your_project:your_dataset.tableA@-600000-]
```

In this step you retrieve all rows changed in last 10 min

2 - Next, you apply logic of transforming (if any) and loading into your_project:your_dataset.tableB

3 - Done

Of course you should implement above steps in [`language`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) of your preference and set it run as a cron job for example

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail !!! I will give it a try and will let you know if it works in my use case.